# how to run multiple scala programs on multiple cores with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have written a scala program with several input args, and then I use a `bash` to set up the program with different parameters, such as

```
sbt "runMain Experiment --profix data --binFile bin/000000.bin --bucketNum 8" &
sbt "runMain Experiment --profix data --binFile bin/000000.bin --bucketNum 16" &
sbt "runMain Experiment --profix data --binFile bin/000000.bin --bucketNum 32" &
sbt "runMain Experiment --profix data --binFile bin/000000.bin --bucketNum 64" &
sbt "runMain Experiment --profix data --binFile bin/000000.bin --bucketNum 128" &
```

The above five programs start to run. However, I found that they share a single CPU core. The server has 28 CPU cores, so the other 27 core is idle. How can I run multiple scala programs on multiple cores?

As shown in the figure, there are three programs, and each of them uses 1/3 of the CPU
[image]

Comment: By default, sbt executes tasks in parallel in an effort to utilize all available processors. You can achieve this programatically using `Tags`. Check [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Parallel-Execution.html).

Comment: I add `Global / concurrentRestrictions := Seq(
  Tags.limit(Tags.CPU, 4)
) `, it seems that the first four programs are running, but they still share the single CPU core